# How to import Angular application created using Node.js and the "ng new" command into a Spring Boot application?

Tags: node.js, spring, angular, spring-boot

I have created an Angular application with the "ng new" command and I can run it on the Node.js server.

But what I want to do is to run the Angular app on the same server as my Spring Boot application. My Spring Boot app runs on the Tomcat server.

Can I just copy the Angular apps files to the resources foldet in the Spring Boot app? Do I copy everything or just some files? Do I need to make a folder structure for these files? Will this work? If not, is there any other way of making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can create build of your angular app using ng build --prod
after that you can put your dist folder present at the angular project root location in your Apache directory. For more about angular deployment you can  use this link https://angular.io/guide/deployment